# SparkContext params for pyspark application on cluster

Tags: pyspark, slurm

I'm trying to run a pyspark application on a cluster and am not sure how to parallelize its execution. When I run the application locally, I initialize the SparkContext as:

```
sc = SparkContext("local", "appname")
```

When I run on the cluster, I changed this to:

```
sc = SparkContext(os.sys['MASTER'], 'appname')
```

where 'MASTER' is set to the master node on the cluster (i.e. spark://node-1:7077). The application starts to run, but then it just stalls (it runs fine on the cluster when I set master to 'local'). My submission script has the following settings:

```
#SBATCH -N 20
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node 4
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task 2
...
spark-submit --total-executor-cores 160 --executor-memory 1024G app.py
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks